# Dr Racket will not save any of my files. Has anyone had this error before or have any ideas?

Tags: racket, dr.racket

I have reinstalled Dr Racket including older versions. No matter what whenever I save I get this error: There was an error saving

bytes->string/locale: string is not a well-formed UTF-8 encoding
string: #"pl\373"

Comment: Looks like your file is corrupt, or has some invalid chars on it. Have you tried creating a new file from scratch? edit it inside Racket and save it, it should work without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the same issue detailed at https://github.com/racket/racket/issues/3498. It's been fixed in the upcoming version. Meanwhile, you can delete the preference file (as detailed in the link above) to fix the issue for your installation.